# Detect Taps in Different areas of a tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

this one has me pretty well stumped so hoping someone can help. I have a tableview that has a custom cell with 3 labels and 2 buttons. If a user taps the label, i use didSelectRowAtIndexPath to set a variable from an array (i.e. variable = array[indexPath.row]) and then perform a segue, passing the info from the variable to a new VC with prepareForSegueWithIdentifier - this works fine and all is well in the world.

I'd like to implement the same functionality for the button within the same cell, however I'm having trouble detecting which row was tapped. I've tried an IBAction from the button where i code "func didSelectRowAtIndexPath" a second time, and it kind of works but the row is inaccurate (for example, it'll pass info for a cell a few below the one I actually tapped) -- I also tried a global variable that would get the row from the original didSelectRowAtIndexPath function but that had similar results.

What is the best practices for doing this? Is there another way to get the row i tapped from a second place within the tableView? Should i have used another label instead of a button?

Any help/ideas is greatly appreciated. Happy to post my code as well if need. Thank you!!

```
import UIKit
import Parse

var rowNumber:Int = 0

class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    var postToWeb:String = ""
    var usernames = [String]()
    var linkArr = [String]()
    var titleArray = [String]()
    var users = [String: String]()
    var createdAt = [String]()
    var userList: [User] = []
    var sortedArticles: [User] = []

    var commentUrl:String = ""
    var commentTitle: String = ""
    var commentUser:String = ""

    struct User {

        var date:NSDate
        var username:String
        var url:String
        var title:String

    }

    let cellSpacingHeight: CGFloat = 10


    class commentButtonClass: UIButton {

        var section:Int = 0


    }

    @IBAction func commentButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        commentTitle = self.userList[rowNumber].title
        commentUrl = userList[rowNumber].url
        commentUser = (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!


        performSegueWithIdentifier("commentView", sender: self)

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var query = PFUser.query()

        query?.orderBySortDescriptor(NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false))

        query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) in

            if let users = objects {

                self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.linkArr.removeAll(keepCapacity:  true)
                self.titleArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.createdAt.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

                for object in users {

                    if let user = object as? PFUser {

                        self.users[user.objectId!] = user.username!

                    }

                }

            }



        let getFollowedUsersQuery = PFQuery(className: "followers")


        getFollowedUsersQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

        getFollowedUsersQuery.orderBySortDescriptor(NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false))

        getFollowedUsersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) in

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    let followedUser = object["following"] as! String

                    let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")

                    query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: followedUser)

                    query.orderBySortDescriptor(NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false))

                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) in

                        //create a struct with createdAt as struct name since will be unique majority of time if include time and date.

                        if let objects = objects {


                            for object in objects {

                                let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                                dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
                                dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
                                let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(object.createdAt!)

                                self.userList.append(User(date: object.createdAt!, username:self.users[object["userId"] as! String]!, url: object["linkURL"] as! String, title: object["title"] as! String))

                                self.userList.sortInPlace{ $0.date.compare($1.date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending  }

                                self.tableView.reloadData()

                            }

                        }

                    })

                }

            }

        }

        })




    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Set the spacing between sections
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return cellSpacingHeight
    }

    // Make the background color show through
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        return headerView
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return userList.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
        let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.userList[indexPath.section].date)

        myCell.titleLabel.text = self.userList[indexPath.section].title

        myCell.userLabel.text = self.userList[indexPath.section].username

        myCell.createdDateLabel.text = dateString

        myCell.rowNumberLabel.tag = indexPath.section

        // add border and color

        myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        myCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        myCell.layer.borderWidth = 2
        myCell.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        myCell.clipsToBounds = true


        return myCell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!;

        rowNumber = indexPath.section

        postToWeb = userList[indexPath.section].url

        print(postToWeb)

        performSegueWithIdentifier("webView", sender: self)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "webView") {

            // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller

            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! WebViewController

            // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value

            vc.passedValue = postToWeb

        }
        if (segue.identifier == "commentView") {

            let commentVc = segue.destinationViewController as! commentsViewController

            commentVc.passedCommentTitle = commentTitle
            commentVc.passedCommentUrl = commentUrl
            commentVc.passedCommentUsername = commentUser

        }
    }
```

in the above, the segue to "webView" works perfectly and the data is passed.  In the commentView - data is passed, but it's incorrect.

Comment: better to post some code. And for such problems, it is better to use delegate in the tableview cell class.

Comment: @surely here's my code for  this view.  I have a custom cell class that's basically just outlets for my labels. My button outlet is in this class "commentButtonPressed" -- pick it apart as much as you like (i'm sure it's very noobish code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the UITableViewCell that was tapped (as an Action of the Button), you have different options:

1) Use Target-Action method, something like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell
    //...More Code

    myCell.myBtn.addTarget(self, action: "myActionMethod:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    //... More Code

    return myCell
}
```

And then define your action method (note, **yourTbl** is an instance of **UITableView**):

```
func myActionMethod(sender:UIButton){
    //base on the hierarchy of the UI
    //Suppose in this case:
    //(UITableView)->(UITableViewCell)->(ContentView)->UIButton then:
    if let tableViewCell = sender.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell, indexPath = yourTbl.indexPathForCell(tableViewCell){
        //Here you have the IndexPath
    }
}
```

2) The same Idea, but basically your going to set the Tag property of the UIButton (to your row cell), and using Target-Action on the sender (parameter) you get the tag of the button.

Update Sample:
https://github.com/Abreu0101/SampleTargetActionMethod

Comment: I made an action of the button into my custom cell, but when I added myCell.myBtn.addTarget (used my button's action name) - i get an error - 'value of type UIButton has no member 'addTarget' Any idea why?

Comment: @jsw324 added a link with a sample.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best practices for doing this?

You need you delegate pattern. See below example.

The `CustomTableViewCell` class:

```
protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate {
    func customTableViewCell(cell: CustomTableViewCell, didTextInLabelChanged text: String)
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: CustomTableViewCellDelegate?

    func handeLabelTextChanged(text: String) {
        delegate?.customTableViewCell!(self, didTextInLabelChanged: text)
    }

    // ... some other code

}
```

The `CustomViewController` class:

```
class CustomViewController {

    // some code

}

class CustomViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = // dequeue the right cell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell

    }

}

class CustomViewController: CustomTableViewCellDelegate {

    func customTableViewCell(cell: CustomTableViewCell, didTextInLabelChanged text: String) {
        // do tableView update with changed text
    }

}
```

As you see all "changed" (or "tapped", or whatever) logic is going on in you cell. To notify controller about this changes you simply create a protocol with all methods what you need (in this case i notify my controller about text in label changed), then you need to create a `var delegate: YourDelegate?` and call it where you need. Next step you need implement "handle" function in your controller. It's very simple. You just need implement the `customTableViewCell()` function from `CustomTableViewCellDelegate` and also set the `delegate` variable to `self` for `CustomTableViewCell`.

---

**UPDATE**

> When a user taps a button within the cell, i need the specific info from that cell, based on the indexPath.row

Very easy. Remember that in your controller you implement the `CustomTableViewCellDelegate`? So, to get specific info from cell you can do this:

```
class CustomViewController: CustomTableViewCellDelegate {

    func customTableViewCell(cell: CustomTableViewCell, didTextInLabelChanged text: String) {

        // here you get `someVariable` from your cell.
        // where `someVariable` you set in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` controller's
        // method
        let info = cell.someVariable

        // or, if for some reason you not save in your cell some data,
        // but you need the `indexPath.row` to get this data you 
        // can find this `indexPath` like this:
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
            let number = youArrayOfNumbers[indexPath.row]
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: makes sense, but how do I implement this for the specific row that was tapped?  For example, I have 3 arrays that populate the cells based on indexPath.row.  When a user taps a button within the cell, i need the specific info from that cell, based on the indexPath.row.

Comment: Thank you for your time!  I couldn't get this one to work, but the solution above took care of me.  Thanks anyway!